# File Dialog from a Background Worker

Tags: c#, multithreading, dialog, backgroundworker

While maintaining some code, I discovered that we have an infinite hang-up in a **background worker**. The worker requires access to a script file. The original code was written to pop up a file dialog if no script file was defined, to allow the user to select one. It looks something like this:

```
private void bgworker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ... snip ...

    if (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(scriptFile))
    {
         scriptFile = PromptForScript();
    }

    ... snip ...
}

private string PrompForScript()
{
    string script = "";
    OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

    if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        script = openDialog.FileName;
    }

    return script;
}
```

I've read up a bit about `MethodInvoker`, but almost all of the invoke methods require that you call them from a control. The background worker in question is **running from a separate class, which doesn't extend `Control`**. Do I use the form that calls the class with the bgworker for that? Or is there another way of interrupting the thread for user input?

Comment: FWIW - one design consideration is to check for the existance of the file (and subsequently prompt the user) before you run the background worker, assuming that the thread is being kicked off by user interaction in the first place.  I generally prefer to keep the "form type" calls (like opening a dialog) within the context of the UI (form) calls, keeping the business logic (running the script) separate.

Comment: Not a pretty solution but, I marshal the call back to the main UI thread, set the filename as a global variable, and then from my sub-class, I call another method that retrieves the global var.  In short, 1.) call for background worker; 2.) bgworker instantiates object of sub-class and calls for method in class which initiates event; 3.) Main Class is listening for event; 4.) inside of event handler, call for method (that contains an InvokeRequired check); 5.) get filename from user on GUI thread; 6.) From sub-class, call another method that retrieves the value of the filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not recommended to invoke the UI from the background worker DoWork event handler.  `BackgroundWorker` is meant to do work on a non-UI thread to keep the UI responsive.  You should ask for any file information before starting the `BackgroundWorker` object with `RunWorkerAsync`.

Comment: This is generally what I'm leaning towards. I'm a very junior programmer working on a fairly large application, so I'm a little hesitant to muck around too much with the structure, but it makes sense to do the check before running the thread.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is capture the [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) on the UI thread and pass that along to the background worker.  The BackgroundWorker can call `Send()` (synchronous, like `Invoke`) and `Post()` (asynchronous, like `BeginInvoke`) on the context to invoke back to the correct UI thread.  That said, there is probably no need for the BackgroundWorker in this case- a regular threadpool thread would do just fine.

This (slightly modified) block of code from http://msmvps.com/blogs/manoj/archive/2005/11/03/74120.aspx should give you the general idea:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Here we are on the UI thread, so SynchronizationContext.Current
    // is going to be a WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext that Invokes properly
    ctx = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
        // This delegate is going to be invoked on a background thread
        s => {
            // This uses the context captured above to invoke
            // back to the UI without the "messy" referencing 
            // of a particular form
            ctx.Send(s2 =>
            {
               // Interact with your UI here- you are on the UI thread
            },null);
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If some Form kicks off a long-running process within another class that uses a BGworker, why wouldn't the form (or presenter, depending on UI architecture) handle the processing of the error state?

Perhaps, just pass back some status [result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.doworkeventargs.result.aspx) (or throw a very targeted, specific exception that you can handle in the UI)?

Leave the background worker to determine if there IS an error, but leave handing the error (especially the UI portion of showing a message box) to the upper layers.

Sorry this didn't have more concrete code but it could go a lot of different ways depending on how your system is architected.

Answer (score -2):

Well, the [`Form`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx) class has an [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) method, so passing the form instance to the background working class should work.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, there is no form class from which to call the invoke methods in this case.

Comment: The form can be passed to the class. OP just said the class isn't a control, and asked whether he could use the form. The short answer is 'yes'.

Comment: Calling Invoke would block the background worker thread waiting for the UI thread to complete the operation; if the UI thread was waiting for the BackgroundWorker in any way (like progress or Completion) you'd have a deadlock.  Not recommended.